# create operator not available in RxJS?

Tags: rxjs

I tried to run the following code:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/create';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

var observable = Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
    observer.next(1);
    observer.next(2);
    observer.next(3);
    observer.complete();
  });
  observable.subscribe(
    value => console.log(value),
    err => {},
    () => console.log('this is the end')
  );
```

But it complains about create operator not found. I already installed rxjs. I examined the node_modules directory and cannot find the create operator. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create` is not an operator, it is just a static method on `Rx.Observable`.

Just remove the import on your first line and everything should be fine.

Comment: Why we should not import static methods while we must import operators?

Comment: I believe operators were done this way so as to make tree-shaking possible. Note that in RXJS5 there is a new pipe method which does away with these add/operator/* imports